# IIS 7 Bad Request response when %0A exists in the URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7

I have an application that was supposed to accept unsafe characters from Salesforce. They are %0A and %0D (so far...) and they're not working.

I've set `allowDoubleEscaping` to `true`, `requestValidationMode` to `2.0`, `requestPathInvalidCharacters` to `BLANK`, `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` to `true` and `maxRequestLength` to `1024`.

It didn't work. Then I tried setting a custom error for 400 to redirect to the same page without passing it the data Salesforce was sending. Also didn't work.

Then I tried doing the same through the IIS 7 Error Pages section and it still didn't work.

How can I:

1. Get the app to accept the characters?
2. Or get the app/IIS to redirect to the same page for manual entry?

All of this is in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application, but I doubt that matters because its probably IIS stopping it before it even calls the ASP.NET runtime.

I'd appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the error coming from ASP.NET or IIS?  You can typically tell the difference, ASP.NET has the YSOD (yellow screen of death), IIS 7 looks ... different.

Comment: IIS probably, it's white and says "Bad Request {HR} HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid."

Comment: @Alex Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm having exactly the same issue with %0A and %0D in URLs.

Comment: @Geekman, I did, but it's been so long I'm not sure what the answer was. In any case, I have `requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,&amp;,:,\"` and `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"` in the Web.config. I also have `Allow Double Escaping` enabled in IIS under Request Filtering > Edit Feature Settings. You can see if it's one of those settings, but like I said, I don't remember any more what made it work.

Comment: @Alex, Everything you listed above is not working for me. May be you can remember anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

Where you probably want to look is in the IIS Manager, click on your server node (or website node), an find the `Request Filtering` icon.  Go to the `URL` tab and here you can either allow specific URL's always, or change the way URL filtering is handled in general.  I'm sure these setting are also avaialble under the  section of the web.config file, but I dont know off hand what all the settings elements and attributes would be (I'm sure you could do a search and find them easily).

You may have to fight past ASP.NET after you fix this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check your URLScan config.
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/476/common-urlscan-scenarios/

Do you happen to have this listed in your [DenyUrlSequences] section?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little too late but for me it worked by changing the configured exceptions using the AllowRestrictedChars registry setting ( as documented in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/820129). The default value is 0, I changed it to 1. If nonzero, Http.sys accepts hex-escaped chars in request URLs that decode to U+0000 – U+001F and U+007F – U+009F ranges.